# Getting linked issues from Jira with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, jira

I try to get linked issues from Jira using Python. It seems to be tricky as number of linked issues in particular issue I am getting is correct but linked issues are not those I am expecting (veryfied with Jira web interface). They seem to be some other issues, even from different project.

My purpose here is to get all linked issues for each issue which has them and check if linked issues have particular status.

Here is what I do:

```
results = jira.search_issues('here query')  
for issueId in results:
    issue = jira.issue(issueId)
    if (issue.fields.issuelinks): 
        for issueLinked in issue.fields.issuelinks:
            if(jira.issue(issueLinked).fields.status != "Done" and jira.issue(issueLinked).fields.status != "Closed"):
                print("id: ", jira.issue(issueLinked).id)
                print("key: ", jira.issue(issueLinked).key)
                print("status: ", jira.issue(issueLinked).fields.status)
                print("summary: ", jira.issue(issueLinked).fields.summary)
```

Did you perhaps experience similar problem?

Comment: See https://bitbucket.org/atlassian_tutorial/jira-rest-tutorial-examples/src/master/python/draw-chart.py for a solid example. The documentation for this is section _Calling the REST API from a script: Graphing image links_ of [Jira REST API examples](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/jira-rest-api-examples/).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I can't give a complete answer, but `issue.fields.issuelinks` is not a list of issues, it is a list of links. Here is one example of use:

```
for link in issue.fields.issuelinks:
    if hasattr(link, "outwardIssue"):
        outwardIssue = link.outwardIssue
        print("\tOutward: " + outwardIssue.key)
    if hasattr(link, "inwardIssue"):
        inwardIssue = link.inwardIssue
        print("\tInward: " + inwardIssue.key)
```

Comment: Parent issue is the one with the outward link

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `jira.issue(issueLinked)` use `jira.issue_link(issueLinked)` to get the real link ressource from the Jira server. You than can access the linked issue by:

```
issue_link = jira.issue_link(issueLinked)
print("Linked issue '%s'" % issue_link.outwardIssue)
```

in which `outwardIssue` is the linked issue object.